# Make Queue thread-safe

Tags: objective-c, ios, thread-safety, locking, nslock

I have a camera session and i am taking images from the buffer:

```
   -(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = (CVPixelBufferRef)CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

    CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];        
    //rotate image 90°
    ciImage = [ciImage imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2.0)];
}
```

And i am applying a filter on the image, and i want it to apply the filter on another queue, it is not thread-safe so if i take images to fast it will blend the images together (50/50 from left to right, i think), but i am trying to make it thread-safe, and it will not work by using [NSLock](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLock_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or NSRecursiveLock because it will blend the images together.

```
dispatch_async(filterQueue, ^{
            CIImage *scaleImage = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CILanczosScaleTransform" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, ciImage, @"inputScale", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5], nil].outputImage;

            CGImageRef cgImage = [imageContext createCGImage:scaleImage fromRect:scaleImage.extent];
            [self.pictureArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage]];
            CGImageRelease(cgImage);
        });
```

Can someone help me? i have not much knowledge in how to make code a thread-safe

Images blend like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjrIl.png

Answer (score 2):

First, the only part of the above code that isn't thread safe is the call to `addObject:`. You can make your code thread-safe by moving your `addObject:` call to the main thread, or by making `pictureArray` accesses more thread-safe. Let's look at both.

## Move the call

This is almost certainly how you'd want to do it.

```
dispatch_async(filterQueue, ^{
  CIImage *scaleImage = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CILanczosScaleTransform" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, ciImage, @"inputScale", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5], nil].outputImage;

  CGImageRef cgImage = [imageContext createCGImage:scaleImage fromRect:scaleImage.extent];
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
  CGImageRelease(cgImage);
  cgImage = NULL; // Always set to NULL after you release something
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.pictureArray addObject:image];
  });
});
```

Note that I'm doing as much as I can on the background thread. I just move the final `addObject:` to the main thread.

## Thread-safe addImage:

If you call `addObject:` often from background threads, it may be nice to hoist this out into its own method like this:

```
- (void)addImageOnMainThread:(UIImage *)image {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.pictureArray addObject:image];
  });
}
```

## Thread-safe pictureArray:

This is better if mutation is very common and locking is a performance problem. Using barriers leads to *very* fast accesses, at the expense of more complicated code.

```
- (UIImage *)imageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
  UIImage *result = nil;
  dispatch_sync(self.pictureArrayQueue, 
    ^{ result = self.pictureArray[index]; });
  return result;
}

- (void)addImage:(UIImage *)image {
  dispatch_barrier_async(self.pictureArrayQueue, 
    ^{ [self.pictureArray addObject:image]; });
}
```

Note that there's a new dispatch queue here for accessing `pictureArray`. You can build more readers and writers (like `removeImageAtIndex:`, etc.) All readers use `dispatch_sync`. All writers use `dispatch_barrier_async`. This requires more code, and you must never directly access `pictureArray` except through these methods. The advantage is that it's much faster if mutation is very common.

Comment: I think the ciImage is not thread-safe because i think ciImage get changed while the filter is creating scaleImage. It must be, because the result is 2 image blended together..

Comment: And i have tried to set the addObject: code on main thread, and the result are the same, 2 image blended together.. :(

Comment: Where does "imageContext" come from? Are you accessing it on multiple threads?

Comment: I am accessing imageContext from multiple threads, but I change it to: `@property (atomic, strong) CIContext *imageContext;`
 **and** 
`viewDidLoad - 
    {self.imageContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];}`
 **and** 
`CGImageRef cgImage = [self.imageContext createCGImage:scaleImage fromRect:scaleImage.extent];`
 But it still get the same result..

Comment: Try bracketing you call to imageWithCVPixelBuffer: with CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress and CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress. I haven't seen documentation that says that's necessary here, but it's the kind of problem I'd expect if you left it out when it was needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use @synchronized(self) to make a code fragment thread safe.

For example:

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)
   //The following code will be thread safe.
   @synchronized(self) {
      CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = (CVPixelBufferRef)CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

      CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];        
      //rotate image 90°
       ciImage = [ciImage imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2.0)];
    }
}
```

The @synchronized statement will lock this section of code to be used for a single thread at once. You can apply it anywhere where you need code to be single threaded.

Hope that helps.

Comment: No it doesn't work :( [images blend like this:](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wjrIl.png)

Comment: try using dispatch_sync to force order of blocks execution

Comment: Is your filterQueue a concurrent queue? You could try to use a serial queue for that.

Comment: filterQueue is serial:
`@interface {
dispatch_queue_t filterQueue;
}`
and
`- (void)viewDidLoad
{
filterQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Filter Queue", NULL);
}`